# Linq Where inside a where

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to compare the values inside the ids array with the ItemID value in the ItemsOfCars table.
ItemsOfCars is a table relationship to many to many.

**As an example, I have values 1,2,3,4,5 in ItemsOfCars.
I have values 1, 2 in the array named ids.
I want to compare them and get the values 3, 4, 5 that are in the ItemsOfCars array but not in the ids array.**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetItems(int[] ids)
    {
       
       foreach (var item in items)
        {
            item.ItemsOfCars.Where(x => x.ItemId == ids)
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "but it doesn't work." - this is not an adequate problem description.

Comment: Make a compound Where using || (OR) or && (And).  You do not need two WHERE.

Comment: Where is `items` defined? What is its type? **POST YOUR ACTUAL CODE**

Comment: https://twitter.com/marcgravell/status/1330430245384679424?s=20

Comment: The LINQ operator you want is `Except`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
public IActionResult GetItems(int[] ids)
    {
   
      var items=  ItemsOfCars.Where(i => !ids.Contains(i.ItemId)); 
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need  foreach (var item in items)? Could you show please where are items defined?

Comment: Calling `Contains` on an array within a loop is generally not a good idea.